# Activity.start throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anyone go through the situation that when invoking Activity.start,it throws ActivityNotFoundException?
Here is the stack trace:

[image]

This project is commercial,so I replace the specific package names with xxx。
Here is the code with which I start the activity:
[image]
Here is the Activity declaration:
[image]

It only happens sometimes.And all the crash logs come from the Flyme system,Meizu mobile phones.
It would be appreciated if someone help me out.Thanks!!!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I meet this problem also. only happens on Meizu.

Answer (score 1):

This Happens some times with me also, I think because of cache. When I do **Run-> clean & Rerun** it works fine for me.

Comment: It happens in release environment.These crash logs come from user's phones.

Comment: @Jake In release I have faced this issue.. I will suggest to clear cache before release and try with full path of activity in declaration in manifest file.

And you have written a static method so. take care while calling you are  passing right Activity in context param.. not getApplicationContext()